# Кастомная вью в качестве пина на карте. Yandex MapKit (Swift)

Tags: swift, yandexmapkit

Подскажите как сделать пин на карте как на картинке. При чем чтобы круг был на точке назначения, а над ним лейбл с картинкой. Пытался сделать все одной вью и подставить через YRTViewProvider. Но ничего не выходит. Отдельно точку получается, отдельно лейбл получается. А вью с точкой, картинкой и лейблом - нет. Так же пробовал один из методов найденных здесь - вью переделывать в UIImage. Но так же безуспешно. Вместо этого на карте просто квадраты без каких либо сабвью. Заранее благодарю.

[image: Placemark]

Comment: Вопрос картинкой - это, конечно, хорошо, наглядно... Но может стоит свой пример кода приводить, который вас не устроил результатом, с уточнением, что в нём не так или не хватает для вашего сценария?

Answer (score 0):

У Яндекса есть [пример](https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-ios-demo/blob/d4a3111894671472c72aad08efebf3338e509a28/MapKitDemo/MapObjectsViewController.swift#L188). Судя вот по этому

> Так же пробовал один из методов найденных здесь - вью переделывать в
> UIImage.

у вас получается view, который при преобразовании в картинку дает не тот результат, которого вы добиваетесь.
Попробуйте добиться такого UIView, чтобы по нему получается правильный UIImage и проверить результат вне мапкит.

Можно попробовать преобразовывать UIView в UIImage с помощью такого кода:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```